# Python Channelizer

Tags: python, matlab, filter, signal-processing

After years of telling myself I would, I'm finally switching from MATLAB to Python.  I am having difficulty finding a Python equivalent to [MATLAB's Channelizer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.channelizer-system-object.html).  Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [PyFilterBank](https://siggigue.github.io/pyfilterbank/index.html) will do the trick.